# How to get all possible quadratic combinations from the numbers of 4 arrays in C++?

Tags: c++

I am having a hard time to figure this out so I need some help. So I have 4 arrays a, b, c and d. And I want to pick 4 numbers from each array and see if their sum equals to x. And then count how many Times The possible combinations' sum equaled x. How can I achieve this???

Comment: what did you try? Please show your code

Comment: The easiest way would be 4 nested `for` loops and a counter (provided that values are within reasonable range and multiplying them won't overflow).

Comment: Smells like homework for me...

Comment: @xryl669 the question wouldn't be any clearer if it wasn't homework. Asking about homework isn't bad per se.

Answer (score 0):

It would look somthing like this

```
int main(){
   int k; int t; int p; int f;
   int x;
   int a[A];
   int b[B];
   int c[C];
   int d[D];
   int s; //count sucesses
   for (k = 0; k < A; k++){
      for (t = 0; t < B; t++){
         for (p = 0; p < C; p++){
            for(f = 0; f < D; f++{
               if ((a[k]+b[t]+c[p]+d[f]) == x){
                  s++;
              }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Be more clear on what you want, if you don't want to repet combinations, the size of the arrays are fix, etc. Show your code.